# Copy data from vmdk files in Windows

Tags: vmware

I've got disk with some vmdk files. Are there any methods to see and copy files from vmdk without booting VM with it? I use Windows 10 Home.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of options:

1) If you have VMware Workstation just map this vmdk and open in Windows. VMDK should be formatted in NTFS/FAT

2) Use 7-zip to extract data - https://www.7-zip.org/

More options and details can be found here - https://www.vmwareblog.org/4-ways-extract-content-vmdk-vm-totally-dead/

P.S. There were definitely  similar topics on superuser, so you can just search here for additional advises.

Comment: As an alternative, you can use StarWind V2V converter as an alternative to convert VMDK to VHDX and then mount it locally on Windows 10. https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-v2v-converter